# Firebase add new child when an item on adapter is non-zero

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Hello so I have a function in an app where you will add a data from the adapter if the quantity is non-zero and it will be saved to the firebase realtime database. What i wanna do is if the other item in adapter is non-zero it will add a child to the database but instead firebase is just replacing the item instead of adding a new child what should i do?

here is the code

```
public class UsualFragRViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <UsualFragRViewAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

    private List<FragmentsUsualModels> items;
    private Context context;

    public UsualFragRViewAdapter( Context context,List<FragmentsUsualModels> items ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_usual_array, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final FragmentsUsualModels arrayitems = items.get(position);
        holder.itemName.setText(arrayitems.getItemName());
        holder.price.setText(String.valueOf("$ " +arrayitems.getPrice()));
        holder.quantity.setNumber(arrayitems.getQuantity());

        holder.card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        holder.quantity.setOnValueChangeListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnValueChangeListener() { //all items are located in its positions
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(ElegantNumberButton view, int oldValue, int newValue) { //Need to pass all non-zero items as chatview
                arrayitems.setQuantity(String.valueOf(newValue));

                if (newValue !=0){
                    String datavalue = holder.itemName.getText().toString();
                    String dataprice = holder.price.getText().toString();
                    String dataquantity = holder.quantity.getNumber().toString();

                    DatabaseReference data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("itemdata");
                    data.child("dataname").setValue(datavalue);
                    data.child("dataprice").setValue(dataprice);
                    data.child("dataquantity").setValue(dataquantity);

                    Log.d(TAG, "the new value of this data is: " +dataquantity);
                    Log.d(TAG, "the itemname of this position is:  "+datavalue);
                    Log.d(TAG, "the price of this item in this position is: " +dataprice);
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "user changed the quantity in this position to " +arrayitems);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView card;
        ImageView image;
        TextView itemName;
        TextView price;
        ElegantNumberButton quantity;
        Button donebtn;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ucard);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.uimage);
            itemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.uitemName);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.uprice);
            quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.uquantity);
            donebtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.udonebtn);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is a method PushChild() be sure to thoroughly look at the reference at Firebase documentation website.

Comment: Cause you are using setValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate a new child node under a location, call `push()` on that `DatabaseReference`. So to create a new child node under `itemdata`:

```
DatabaseReference data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("itemdata");
DatabaseReference newData = data.push();
```

Now you can write the data to this new location as:

```
newData.child("dataname").setValue(datavalue);
newData.child("dataprice").setValue(dataprice);
newData.child("dataquantity").setValue(dataquantity);
```

---

One additional change to consider is the reducing the number of writes. Your current code does a separate `setValue()` call for each property. This works, but it means that any listeners will get called three times, once for each property.

While this may be what you want, it is quite common to want these writes to appear as one operation. If that is the case, you can perform a single `setValue()` with:

```
Map<String,Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("dataname", datavalue);
values.put("dataprice", dataprice);
values.put("dataquantity", dataquantity);
newData.setValue(values);
```

The end result will be exactly the same as before, but now with a single write operation.

Comment: So that's why it's getting overwritten? because the child has only the same name? and using hashkeys will solve this problem?

Comment: The using of `DatabaseReference newData = data.push()` is what ensures that a new child node is generated for your values. The hashmap solves another problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use push() to create unique id for database item

```
dataBase.child(/*CHILD*/).push().setValue(dataValue);
```